# How to convert Signal to SignalProducer

Tags: ios, reactive-cocoa, reactive-cocoa-3

Unfortunately some RAC pieces does not offer `SignalProducer`s, but `Signal`s — like `Action` has a `values` field which is `Signal`. But for my logic I need the `SignalProducer`.

How can I convert `Signal` to `SignalProducer`?

`toSignalProducer(toRACSignal(x))` does not seem to be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Currently I stopped on this extension:

```
extension Signal {

    func toSignalProducer() -> SignalProducer<T, E> {
        return SignalProducer { (sink, compositeDisposable) in
            compositeDisposable.addDisposable(self.observe(sink))
        }
    }

}
```